# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
>import tensorflow

>import tensorflow.contrib

>tensorflow.contrib

module 'tensorflow.contrib' from 'D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\contrib\\__init__.py'

>import tensorflow.python

>tensorflow.python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

As you can see, I run this code in a cmd(win 10). Both "import tensorflow.contrib" and "import tensorflow.python" are OK, but commands "tensorflow.contrib" and "tensorflow.python" are different. One returns a directory and the other returns AttributeError.

Does anyone have a clue why?

Comment: I think pip install -U keras should do it

Comment: Actually I have the latest keras module, but thanks all the same.

Answer (score 16):

`tensorflow.__init__()` explicitly deletes its reference to the `tensorflow.python` module after importing everything from it.

The reason for that is to provide access to the submodules contained in the `python` package in the top-level `tensorflow` namespace. A few things from the `tensorflow.core` package are also imported and made available in the `tensorflow` namespace.

I think that the idea is *not* to import `tensorflow.python` directly. Those classes, objects, and submodules of `python` that are intended to be used by applications are made available simply by `import tensorflow`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think this sounds reasonable.

Comment: @mhawke The thing that bothers me is that the statement `import tensorflow.python` does not lead to the `AttributeError`. Any chance you have an explanation for that?

Comment: @MrTsjolder: the import succeeds without `AttributeError` because the package exists. Why should it fail? The thing is that when `import tensorflow.python` is executed, `tensorflow` is imported first, _before_ `tensorflow.python`. `tensorflow.__init__.py` explicitly imports what it wants from `tensorflow.python` then deletes the reference to `python` so it is not in the namespace of the importing code. Because `tensorflow.python` was already imported, it is not imported again, so the deleted reference remains deleted.

Comment: so where does this lead the import of tensorflow.python.keras?

Answer (score 2):

You can import `tensorflow.python` the following way:

```py
from tensorflow import python as tf_python
```

Answer (score -4):

Worked for me by using the following import line:

```py
from tensorflow.python import keras
```

Cheers!