# Where Tensorflow EagerTensor is defined?

Tags: tensorflow

In my code I want to check whether returned object type is `EagerTensor`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import inspect

if __name__ == '__main__':

    tf.enable_eager_execution()
    iterator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).__iter__()
    elem = iterator.next()
    print(type(elem))
    print(inspect.getmodule(elem))
    assert type(elem) == tf.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

But the result is:

```
<class 'EagerTensor'>
<module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' from '/home/antek/anaconda3/envs/mnist_identification/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antek/.PyCharm2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 11, in <module>
    assert type(elem) == tf.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

Here: [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304999/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-python) I found out that tensorflow purposely deletes its reference to the python module. So how can I check that my object is an EagerTensor instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if you can, but I think you probably don't need to. You already have the following tools:

- `tf.is_tensor` (previously `tf.contrib.framework.is_tensor`) that will return `True` for an `EagerTensor`
- `tf.executing_eagerly` that returns `True` if you are, well, executing eagerly.

I believe they should cover 99% of your needs -- and I would be curious to hear about your problem if it falls in that percentage left out.

Comment: I didn't know about that first function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the modern version of TensorFlow (2.2), you can use the `is_tensor` function documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/is_tensor).

```
assert(tf.is_tensor(elem))
```