# How to choose from "tensorflow.keras" and "tensorflow.python.keras" in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Currently in tensorflow 2.0, `Keras` can be imported by both `tensorflow.keras` and `tensorflow.python.keras`. What's the difference and how should I choose from these two imports?

```py
from tensorflow.keras import *
from tensorflow.python.keras import *
```

From my understanding, `tensorflow.python.keras` is pretty much the same as the python package Keras, while `tensorflow.keras` is implemented by TensorFlow which might be more compatible with TF, but do not have all packages as in Keras such as Layer, InputSpec, etc.

One other issue is that for some IDEs like PyCharm, they cannot find or auto-complete packages from `tensorflow.keras`, and the temporary solution is to use `tensorflow.python.keras` instead. (from [tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26502))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0, tf.keras is recommended. This version is stable now.

Answer (score 0):

`tensorflow.keras` and `tensorflow.python.keras` are exactly the same package, what tells you that they are different?

You are not supposed to use `tensorflow.python` imports directly, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306203/6108843

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using tensorflow 2.0. In 2.0, some packages in keras are missing such as `tensorflow.keras.layers.InputSpec`. And if they are exactly the same, why does tensorflow keep both of them?

Comment: @junhuizh The answer to that is available in the other answer I linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306203/6108843

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version of Tensorflow, it is recommended to use tensorflow.keras
This is likely due to depreciation since TF is evolving rapidly.