# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python' in Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

System Info :

- keras        2.3.1
- pip          20.2.2
- python       3.6.10
- tensorflow   2.3.0

I am working on a siamese algorithm on keras tensorflow backend. I have imported keras backend as follow and it shows above attribute error. What could be the reason for that and how to avoid this issue?

```
import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K
```

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304999/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-python)

Comment: from tensorflow.keras import backend as k . can you try it with this

Comment: yes i have already tried from tensorflow.keras import backend as k. but it did not worked @gautamrk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that within the module 'tensorflow', no attribute named 'python' exists. You don't really need to import python as a module I believe. Try this:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```